# Display partial response including styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When I make a rest call in react, I get a `style` and `html` response as follows. Is not in String format.
How can I display this in `React` as a partial html fragment?

Bear in mind I can't just use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
That will take care of the html yes. But will not recognise the style.

```
// This won't capture styles.
const Partial = ({ html }) => {
    return (
      <span
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: html.toString(),
        }}
      />
    );
  };
  
export default Partial;
```

There are hundreds of styles and hundreds of elements here. The following is just a sample.
Trying to achieve this without any additional libs.

This is the response, not in String format. Believe is text/html.

```
<style>
    .sample {
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* hundreds of other styles */
</style>
<style>
    .sample2 {
        padding: 0;
    }
    /* hundreds of other styles */
</style>
<!-- many other style tags -->
<div>
    test
    <div>another</div>
    /* hundreds of other elements */
</div>
<div>
    test
    <div>another</div>
    /* hundreds of other elements */
</div>
```